# Jersey PreMatching Filter : Adding parameters to modified URI

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-1.0

I have a rest api. Eg :

```
http://localhost:8080/api/user/view?name=user&lastname=demo
```

I want to modify my URI to maintain version.
I want to add '**/v1/**' between '**/user/view**'
So that my URI will look like as follows :

```
http://localhost:8080/api/user/v1/view?name=user&lastname=demo
```

I am able to modify my URI and create a new one , but I am not understanding how to pass parameters to the modified URI.

The following is my code :

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class RewriteUrl implements ContainerRequestFilter {

 @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        UriInfo uriInfo = requestContext.getUriInfo();

        String path = uriInfo.getPath();

        MultivaluedMap<String, String> parameters = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();

        path=path.replaceFirst("/","/v1/");   

        URI baseUri = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder().path(path).build();

        URI requestUri = uriInfo.getRequestUri();

        requestContext.setRequestUri(URI.create(baseUri.toString()));



     }

}
```

Using the above code I am getting the correct URI :

```
http://localhost:8080/api/user/v1/view
```

But I am not understanding how to pass the parameters to the new URI.

**I also want to know that is this the right and secure way to do this ?
Or      I am doing wrong.**

Please let me know if their is a better way to do this.(adding 'v1' in the URI).

The following I found while debugging :

**PRE - MATCHING FILTER**

```
uriInfo.getRequestUri().toString()   http://localhost:8080/api/user/view?name=user&lastname=demo

uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().toString()  http://localhost:8080/api/user/view

uriInfo.getBaseUri().toString()  http://localhost:8080/api/

uriInfo.getPath().toString() user/view

parameters.toString() {lastname=[demo], name=[user]}
```

**POST FILTER**

```
uriInfo.getRequestUri().toString()   http://localhost:8080/api/user/v1/view

uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().toString()  http://localhost:8080/api/user/v1/view

uriInfo.getBaseUri().toString()  http://localhost:8080/api/

uriInfo.getPath().toString() user/v1/view

parameters.toString() {}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to add the query parameters again. Did you check in your resource method for them? Or are you trying to add new ones?

Comment: Yes I debugged and checked my new URI in the post filter and I am getting the new URI without parameters.

Comment: Why are you checking the URI. Check the query parameters map. That's what matters

Comment: Sir I have edited my question and added the parameters which I am getting in the filters.

Comment: Have you tried to just call `path(path).queryParam(.., ..)`

Comment: Nope I gone through this but I am not understanding how will I pass queryParam(String string , Object os).
I mean for this I have to parse my  MultivaluedMap<String, String> parameters. Actually I am not getting how to put my parameters inside queryParam.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111693/discussion-between-shivkumar-mallesappa-and-peeskillet).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if still relevant, I also had to implement this recently.
Here is my solution:

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class RewriteUrl implements ContainerRequestFilter {
 @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws 
    IOException {
        UriInfo uriInfo = requestContext.getUriInfo();

        String path = uriInfo.getPath();

        path = path.replaceFirst("/","/v1/");   

        UriBuilder uriBuilder = UriBuilder
                     .fromUri(uriInfo.getBaseUri())
                     .path(path)
                     .replaceQuery(uriInfo.getRequestUri().getQuery());

        requestContext.setRequestUri(uriBuilder.build());
    }
}
```